# Maximize $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}p^i\log(x_i)$ where $x_i\ge 0, \sum x_i\le 1.$

Tags: inequality, optimization

I came across this problem while trying to learn some economics. I have a $p\in (0, 1)$ and I have to maximize the sum $$U((x_i)):=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}p^i\log(x_i),$$
where $x_i\ge 0$ and $\sum x_i\le 1.$

Since the maximizer, if it exists, for the above problem and $(1-p)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}p^i\log(x_i)$ would be the same. I use Jensen's inequality to conclude that $U(x_i)\le 0.$ Therefore, a natural thing to try is to come up with a suitable $(x_i)$ such that the above sum is indeed zero. My guess is that the maximizer does not exist. My argument is as follows.

It is easy to see that $x_i>0$ for all $i$ and $x_i\ge x_{i+1}$ (otherwise just interchanging $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ yields a better estimate). Using these two facts, I argue that $$log(x_0)+p\log(x_1)+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}p^i\log(x_i)\le \log(x_0+\epsilon)+p\log(x_1-\epsilon)+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}p^i\log(x_i),$$
for sufficiently small $\epsilon.$ In other words, given any vector $x_i$ with $x_i>0$ for all $i,$ we can modify it to obtain a vector with better $U.$ Is this argument correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's treat this as a straight constrained maximization problem.  Most econ problems would probably have some return to $x_i$ you don't eat today, but this seems to mean there is no loss or gain to storage.

Form the Lagrangean,
$$L=\sum_0^\infty p^i log(x_i)-\lambda(\sum_0^\infty x_i -1).$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i}=p^i\frac{1}{x_i} -\lambda = 0.$$
$$\frac{p^i}{x_i}=\lambda.$$
$$x_i=\frac{p^i}{\lambda}.$$
Now use the constraint
$$\sum\frac{p^i}{\lambda}=1$$
or
$$\lambda = \sum p^i$$
or
$$x_i = (p^i)(1-p)$$.
Intuitively, you want to smooth your consumption, that is, don't pig out today if it means you starve tomorrow, but today is worth more than  tomorrow, so spread things out in a declining manner.

Comment: Your last formula should be $x_i  = (1-p)p^i$ since $\lambda$ is $1/(1-p)$ rather than $1-p$.

Comment: A related result for the geometric distribution $x_i = (1-p)p^i$ is that it maximizes entropy among all probability distributions on $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with mean $m > 0$, where $p \in (0,1)$ is chosen so that $m = p/(1-p)$.

Comment: Of course. thanks @KCd.